# classList.toggle() does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, frontend

I try to add a class called "finished" as soon as an event is fired. I'm trying to achieve this with classList.toggle() but somehow, it doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
let checked = document.getElementsByClassName("single-note");
checked.classList.toggle("finished");
```

Testing it in the console, checked works and gives me back the elements. But toggle doesn't add any classes, it shows "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined". I also already tried it with .add and .contains, but this doesn't work either, giving me the same error message. I know it must have something to do with classList, but I don't know what I'm missing out.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("single-note")[0];`

Comment: You could change `document.getElementsByClassName("single-note");` to `let checked = document.querySelector(".single-note");`. That would solve the issue.

Comment: @Simon .querySelector only adresses the first occurence, doesn't it? But I want to get all the divs with that classname.

Comment: It will only affect the first instance. To get all instances you could use something like this `let checked = document.querySelectorAll(".single-note");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(checked, function(el, i){
el.classList.toggle("finished");
});`